# WEBException was unhandled: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, webclient

I am implementing REST service and I am getting the above error. I searched a lot and used different methods to resolve this error but no luck. The service is working fine when I am using Postman or fiddler. [image: POSTMAN] [image: Fiddler]

Here is my code :

```
try
{
  string content = string.Empty;
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://api.MYDOMAIN.com/servlet/Year"));
  httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
  string parsedContent = "{\"securitykey\":\"KEY\"}";
  var data = JObject.Parse(parsedContent);
  Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());
  httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
  httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
  Stream newStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
  newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  newStream.Close();
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
  var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
  if (stream != null)
  {
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
  throw;
}
```

So in the above code I tried with :

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
HttpUtility.UrlEncode()
```

I also tried the below code but it is giving me the same error :

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
  result = client.UploadString("https://api.MYDOMAIN.com/servlet/Year", "POST", "{\"securitykey\":\"MYKEY\"}");
}
```

I added the security key in raw header as `httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("{\"securitykey\":\"MYKEY\"}")` but still no luck.

Really appreciate if I can get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of RND I tried doing this in PHP, so it gave me an error as UserAgent is required. I added `httpWebRequest.UserAgent` and it worked. This error was never displayed in `WebException`.